# Set values on a new table from a historical table, before adding new table back into historical table

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I would like to create a historical view of alerts in an application. To do this, I am grabbing all events and timestamping them, then uploading them into a MS SQL table. I would also like to be able to exempt certain objects from the total count by flagging either the finding (to exclude the finding across all systems) or the object in the finding (to exclude the object from all findings).

The idea is, I will have all previous alerts in the main table, then I will set an 'exemptobject' or 'exemptfinding' bit column in the row. When I re-run the script weekly, I will upload the results directly into a temporary table and then I would like to compare either the object or the finding for each object in the temporary table to the main database's 'object' or 'finding' and set the respective 'exemptobject' or 'exemptfinding' bit. Once all the temporary table's objects have any exemption bits set, insert the temporary table into the main table and drop the temporary table to keep a historical record.

This will give me duplicate findings and objects, so I am having difficulty with the merge command:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
MERGE INTO [dbo].[temp_table]
     USING [dbo].[historical]
        ON [dbo].[temp_table].[object] = [dbo].[historical].[object] OR
       [dbo].[temp_table].[finding] = [dbo].[historical].[finding]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
           UPDATE
              SET [exemptfinding] = [dbo].[historical].[exemptfinding]
                 ,[exemptobject] = [dbo].[historical].[exemptobject]
                 ,[exemptdate] = [dbo].[historical].[exemptdate]
                 ,[comments] = [dbo].[historical].[comments];
COMMIT
```

This seems to do what I want, but I see that the results are going to grow exponentially and I think it won't be sustainable for long.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE [dbo].[temp]
   SET [dbo].[temp].[exemptfinding] = [historical].[exemptfinding]
      ,[dbo].[temp].[exemptobject] = [historical].[exemptobject]
      ,[dbo].[temp].[exemptdate] = [historical].[exemptdate]
      ,[dbo].[temp].[comments] = [historical].[comments]
  FROM [dbo].[temp] temp
INNER JOIN [dbo].[historical] historical
        ON (
             [temp].[finding] = [sci].[finding] OR
             [temp].[object] = [sci].[object] OR
       ) AND
       (
         [historical].[exemptfinding] = 1 OR
         [historical].[exemptobject] = 1
       )
COMMIT
```

I feel like I need to normalize the database, but I can't think of a way to separate things out and be able to:

1. See a count of each finding based on date the script was run
2. Be able to drill down into each day and see all the findings, objects and recommendations for each
3. Control the count shown for each finding by removing 'exempted' findings OR objects.

I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing or I'm thinking about this incorrectly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT - The following seems to do what I want, but as soon as I add an additional WHERE condition to the final result, the query time goes from 7 seconds to 90 seconds, so I fear it will not scale.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE [dbo].[temp]
   SET [dbo].[temp].[exemptrecommendation] = [historical].[exemptrecommendation]
      ,[dbo].[temp].[exemptfinding] = [historical].[exemptfinding]
      ,[dbo].[temp].[exemptobject] = [historical].[exemptobject]
      ,[dbo].[temp].[exemptdate] = [historical].[exemptdate]
      ,[dbo].[temp].[comments] = [historical].[comments]
  FROM (
    SELECT *
      FROM historical h
     WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT id
             ,recommendation
         FROM temp t
        WHERE (
          t.id = s.id OR
          t.recommendation = s.recommendation
        )
     )
  ) historical
WHERE [dbo].[temp].[recommendation] = [historical].[recommendation] OR
      [dbo].[temp].[id] = [historical].[id]
COMMIT
```

Comment: I do not fully understand your setup but I suggest you "normalise" your design by recording excluded objects/findings in a separate table. It should give you a much smaller table and therefore much better performance.

Comment: On a side note: Google "sql server why merge is bad".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Alex! The more I think about your suggestion, the more sense it makes. I can take all the findings from our security product, dump them as is in the database to get my 'counts' for each scan, and then just exclude the items that match in an exemptobjects or exemptfindings table. I think I was trying to hard to either normalize everything or keep everything in one big table to query against. I think your recommendation is exactly what I need - I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Let us know how it goes.